# Virtual Machine Manager not running ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, virtual-machine-manager

So I've downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.4 iso file and I've tried to run it on qemu, but it gives the following error:

```
This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU:
pae cmov
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

So then with less hope, I tried to run this on Virtual Machine Manager, but of course, it gave me an error:

```
Unable to complete install: 'XML error: No PCI buses available'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2119, in _do_async_install
    guest.installer_instance.start_install(guest, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/installer.py", line 419, in start_install
    doboot, transient)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/installer.py", line 362, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3732, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: XML error: No PCI buses available
```

I am using the raspberry pi 4 to run ubuntu on qemu/virtual machine manager by the way.

Comment: Are you attempting to boot a x86 or ARM image of Ubuntu because `pae` and `cmov` are both features of x86. I mean one is literally an x86 assembly instruction.  While ARM has something similar to Physical Address Extension (PAE) it does not specifically support it. You cannot boot x86 VMs on an Rasp Pi 4

Comment: @Ramhound Is there a 32 bit option of downloading the iso file of ubuntu?

Comment: What? What does that have to do with the fact you cannot run a x86 operating system on ARM hardware?

Comment: There are a few Ubuntu ISOs for ARM specifically. But make sure to select a supported release. 16.04 is not.